# Search and count matches in two arrays by ID in JavaScript or Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two arrays, users and places, each one contains userId, in places and Id(in users), userId and id are the same:

[image]

... so joined this arrays like:

```
  const result = users.map(placeA => {
    return places
        .filter(placeB => placeB.userId === placeA.id)
});
```

...and i got sorted per users, each one with his places like:

[image]

Each user may have a lot of places or none (if none will be 0), each place array contains points:

[image]

In the ionic app front end i have a list of users, each one with profile photo, user name, and i need to extract and show the points, based on user points, sort the list of those users like ranking, users with more points on top...

How can i get the sum of all user places for each user?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce it
Like this:

```
places.reduce((userPlaces, place)=> {
    userPlaces[place.userId] = userPlaces[place.userId] || 0;
    userPlaces[place.userId] += place.points;
    return userPlaces;
}, [])
```

The expected output is an array where you will find userIds as indexes and sums of points value for all the user's places as the value for each position.

Comment: I need to return user place points sum. Imagine 3 users, A,B and C, user A has 4 places, B -> 2 and C none. C must show 0, A the sum of the points from the 4 places column where user.id = place.userId, and B the sum of 2 places points.

Comment: Ok. I edited the code. Check it out and let me know if it works as intended.

Comment: Thanks, and how can i print it for each user, pair with ID -> Points? I'm using Ionic 4

Comment: reduce is using an object which sends to every iteration of the loop. The initial value of this object (userPlaces) is an empty array. During reduce execution, it checks whether the index (userId) exists. If so, it adds the points value of that place, otherwise it will assign a 0 to that index and then perform the addition.
What you would need to achieve what you said is to assign an object with the keys. like this: userPlaces[place.userId] = userPlaces[place.userId] || {id: place.userId, pointCount: 0};
Then the addition would look like userPlaces[place.userId].pointCount += place.points;

Comment: But, if you're already using javascript, then you could just get the index.
i.e. userPlaces.forEach((pointCount, index) => console.log('User id is ' + index + ', point number is ' + pointCount))